# How to hide the "Add new comment" link on the add new comment page

Tags: comments, 10

In Drupal 8+, the "Add comment" form can be shown on a separate page by going to **Manage fields** for the content type that has comments and unchecking the box *Show reply form on the same page as comments.*

This shows an **Add new comment** link on the node (in this case, an article):

[image: article with default display settings]

The UX problem is that when you click the **Add new comment** link, you are taken to a new path (for example, `comment/reply/node/2/comment#comment-form`) but the **Add new comment** link is still there:

[image: add new comment link on add new comment form]

This is confusing because clicking the link merely returns you to the page you are already on, so it may appear that nothing has happened.

How can I remove this "Add new comment" link only on entities that have the comment form embedded (`/comment/reply/entity/entity_id`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_links__node(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('field_name') === 'comment') {
    unset($variables['links']['comment-add']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (assuming you dont want it on the teaser too if its there):

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Remove the "Add new comment" link on teasers or when the comment form is
  // displayed on the page.
  if ($variables['teaser'] || !empty($variables['content']['comments']['comment_form'])) {
    unset($variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
  }
}
```

Comment: The screenshot shows the default view mode at /node/1.  So (as I understand it) what makes this difficult to fix is that the default view mode is used for both `/node/1` and `/comment/reply/node/1`.